# perl: how I can deal with multiple sockets using select AND fork?

Tags: perl, nonblocking

I'm working in a small project where I need to read something from one source (file, socket, etc) ,process and write in many clients (and it is different for each new client).

I'm using select to multiplexing the I/O.

If I can_read the source, I store in an internal buffer, process and write in many output buffers (one per client). If I can_write I just write the buffer. Sounds good.

But How I can scale this for a great number of users? I was thinking in using fork and set something like x connections per process. I really don't know if it is a good way or it is better preforking or work with different ports and use some load balance BUT right now it is not clear to me how can I deal with fork + select

for example, if I work with 100 clients per process, in the 101th cliente I will fork but I still have the old select and 100 sockets clients in memory. I can clean the "old" select and start a new one but it is strange. I don't know if my strategy is good enought.

Comment: Are threads available in the version of PERL you are using?  You could accept the socket and then create a thread using that socket you accepted. Then each client would get a thread to respond to them.  You would not have to fork a process that way and each connection to each client is independent from each other.

Comment: the problem with threads is the GIL

Comment: @Glenn Perl threads is not system threads. Its more heavy operation than fork actually. You can search in internet alitle and see that forking better than threads in Perl. Maybe [forks](http://search.cpan.org/~rybskej/forks-0.34/lib/forks.pm) is good replacement module

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj beware, select() isn't very scalable, after all! Descriptors to be polled are represented in a form of a bitmask, which is both limited (1024 descriptors is max) and suboptimal approach. More info: http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/poll-vs-select.html I guess you should use IO::Poll instead.

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj: there is no GIL in Perl, like there is in cpython or cruby. That's nonsense.

Comment: @PSIAlt: Perl threads are system threads. However, their creation is rather expensive because it has to clone a lot of data. For most purposes, forking performs better unless you need things to work on Windows (where forking is emulated using threads, with limited success).

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is made with "prefork" technique. This works like that:

1) Create listening socket

2) `fork()` to make N workers

3) Each worker begin `accept()` clients (most free worker will take the job); Meanwhile "parent" process becomes "manager" and `waitpid()` his childs, forking if number of "workers" < N

But this way you cannot send data between "workers" (as in your initial case with 101th client in other process), so maybe this design not fit your needs. In this case i'd prefer to use [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-7.04/lib/AnyEvent.pm) CPAN module. This enables you asyncronous working with way more clients at a time, since it uses epoll/kqueue for multiplexing and its scalable to thousands connects on one signle process (if your script isnot CPU-heavy).

Answer (score 2):

If you are not averse to writing your application around a framework, might I suggest the rather venerable and award-winning *multi-tasking/networking* framework on CPAN, [POE](http://poe.perl.org/).

It basically provides a kernel and event loop around `select` (that's an oversimplification). You write callbacks. Do `x` when event `e` occurs, that sort of thing. It's ideal for concurrently reading/writing from/to multiple sources, irrespective of whether they are sockets, files, or terminals.  It takes some getting used to but it very useful. There's a bunch of [good examples](http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook).

For example, if you want to scale by pre-forking a pool of processes, POE provides something to manage that easily: [http://metacpan.org/pod/POE::Wheel::Run](http://metacpan.org/pod/POE%3a%3aWheel%3a%3aRun)

And if you need a TCP server that handle concurrent clients, there's this: [http://metacpan.org/pod/POE::Component::Server::TCP](http://metacpan.org/pod/POE%3a%3aComponent%3a%3aServer%3a%3aTCP)

Note that it *does not* use threads; it is a form of cooperative multitasking using event loops and callbacks. If the processing you need to do per request takes only negligible time, then that's all you need, but if you want to delegate some work that might block to a pool of preforked processes then that's easy too, with `POE::Wheel::Run`.

Comment: Thanks but my first interest is understand better what is behind POE and AnyEvent. For example, POE has too much extra code and it can be good (can save from much other problems) or bad, if I need performance (ok... it is not a good answer, we are talking about microseconds) or if I can't install POE (to save space in some environment with huge restrictions of size and permissions). But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach for this is pre-forking some number of worker processes, and then [passing file descriptors](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch17lev1sec4.html) of newly accepted client sockets to them, say in some round-robin fashion, for further processing over UNIX domain sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand your requirement correctly, but if you are getting input from one source and copying the output to multiple sources you might want to look at PubSub systems  like ZeroMQ. See http://zeromq.org/ and https://metacpan.org/module/ZMQ

This presumes that you is not bound by a specific protocol between the clients and the server.